# cygwin-backed exe killed by taskkill, will always return 0, any work-around?

Tags: cygwin

I find such a problem. Assuming I have a C program `sleepret.c`, compiled with gcc inside cygwin.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sec = 0;
    if(argc>1)
        sec = atoi(argv[1]);
    
    sleep(sec);
    return sec & 1;
}
```

I'm using cygwin1.dll 3.1.4 on Window 8.1.

Now, run `sleepret.exe 10`. During its sleeping, from another cygwin terminal, I use `ps` to identify its PID and `kill -9 <pid>`, then the `sleepret`'s caller can identify its return value(process exit code) is 143 via `$?`. That's utterly correct behavior, so far so good.

[image: D:\chjkeep\hypersnap\Snap2824 cygwin exe by unix kill.png]

However, if I kill `sleepint.exe` with Windows native `taskkill /F /IM sleepint.exe`, **the `$?` will always be 0**, which means, `sleepint`'s caller will not be able to know whether `sleepint` results in success.

[image: D:\chjkeep\hypersnap\Snap2826 sleepret taskill return 0.png]

Then, how to workaround this issue?

Comment: I think I've run into this problem before. I'd be happy if anyone knows otherwise, but I think this is an inherent limitation. If you kill the process from outside Cygwin then it will have no opportunity to set the exit code. One workaround, if a bit ugly, is have your program print a message upon normal exit, and wrap it in a script that checks for that message.